# string strip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  would   need   to stripoff "domain\"  from  "domain\name"   to extract name  which can   be any name or the  word name  literally

```
>>> s="domain\name"

>>> x=s[5:]
>>> print(x)
n
ame
>>> s="domain\bh16"
>>> x=s[5:]
>>> print(x)
h16
>>> x=s[4:]
>>> print(x)
ih16
```

Comment: FWIW, your first string doesn't actually have a backslash in it ... `\n` is a newline...

Comment: and `\b` is an ["ASCII backspace"](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), I don't think you want that!

Comment: where are you getting these from? If under your control return these results as raw strings.

Comment: Assuming this is a path or url, I would use `os.basename(path)` to get the filename from a path/url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to a raw string and use `replace` as normal

```
s = r"domain\bh16"

print(s.replace("domain\\", '')) #bh16
```

Comment: the   solution you gave  me   works    fine   when I  know   the    value   of variable   's'. However, I am using it in a code  where s  gets assigned   dynamically to different names  with 'domain\'  prefixed to it . If I try that  way   the  solution is not working  >>> Username='corp\bh16'
>>> y=r"Username"
>>> print(y)
Username